# How to figure out source process of IP traffic in NETunnelProviderManager

Tags: ios, networking, process, ip, networkextension

I am using NETunnelProviderManager in the "routing by destination IP" mode, and I am able to get IP traffic from various apps on the device.

The issue is that I need to determine which application each IP packet has come from so I can filter and block traffic as needed, in order to prevent a rogue app accessing an internal location. It is not feasible for me to use NETunnelProviderManager's "per-app" mode since I am not using MDM. Unfortunately, Apple's app proxy provider also requires MDM.

It seems that if I had access to the system's TCB table (or access to the TCB table for each process) I could do this, but it looks like iOS does not publish this information and I haven't found any private APIs either to get this information on a non-jailbroken device.

Does anyone know of any techniques I can use?

Comment: I don't think that's possible technically nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it exist on jailed phones. At least there is nothing in public API's which allows it.